# iOS - Firebase Observe Single Event Calling Twice

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, observer-pattern

I am relatively new to Firebase and iOS development so I was hoping someone could give me some guidance on what I am doing wrong. For some reason, the code block within my Observe is being run twice, even though ObserveSingleEvent is specifically supposed to terminate the observing after the initial data is read.

Something I want to note is that this is only occurring on my phone(iPhone 7 iOS10). I have a totally different issue when I run it in the simulator, I get one call like it is supposed to, however, the call is made while my view is still in the previous view. Essentially, this function is supposed to be called after the main screen loads its view. However, in the simulator, when I authenticate my user in the login screen, it creates the popup if I don't have an username, and doesn't actually present the next view to the main screen.

Here is the function causing problems:

```
func initialSetUp() {
    print("initially set up")
    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/users/").child("\(uid!)")
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("observing event")
        print("\(snapshot)")

        if snapshot.hasChild("username"){
           print("user has username")
        } else {
            print("user does not have username")
            //do stuff
            let nameRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/usernames/")
            let alert = SCLAlertView()
            let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
                kTitleFont: UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 20)!,
                kTextFont: UIFont(name: "Futura-Medium", size: 14)!,
                kButtonFont: UIFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 14)!,
                showCloseButton: false,
                shouldAutoDismiss: false
            )
            alert.appearance = appearance
            let newName = alert.addTextField("Enter your name")
            alert.addButton("Check name", backgroundColor: UIColor.black, textColor: UIColor.white, showDurationStatus: false) {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
                if let name = newName.text {
                    if name != "" {
                    //check if username is unique
                        nameRef.child(name.lowercased()).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            print("\(snapshot.value)")
                            if !snapshot.exists() {
                                let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                                alertView.showSuccess("Woohoo!", subTitle: "This username is valid!")
                                print("valid username")
                            } else {
                                let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                                alertView.showError("Sorry :(", subTitle: "This username has already been taken.")
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                        alertView.showError("Sorry :(", subTitle: "Your name can't be blank!")
                    }
                }

            }
            alert.addButton("Done", backgroundColor: UIColor.black, textColor: UIColor.white, showDurationStatus: false) {
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)
                if let name = newName.text {
                    if name != "" {
                        //check if username is unique
                        nameRef.child(name.lowercased()).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            print("\(snapshot.value)")
                            if !snapshot.exists() {
                                alert.hideView()
                                let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                                alertView.showSuccess("Success!", subTitle: "You're all set to go!")
                                userRef.child("username").setValue(name)
                                nameRef.updateChildValues([name.lowercased(): self.uid])
                            } else {
                                let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                                alertView.showError("Sorry :(", subTitle: "This username has already been taken.")
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        let alertView = SCLAlertView()
                        alertView.showError("Sorry :(", subTitle: "Your name can't be blank!")
                    }
                }
            }
            alert.showCustom("Username", subTitle: "Please pick a user name!", color: UIColor.black, icon: SCLAlertViewStyleKit.imageOfEdit)
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.mapViewController.view)
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableController.view)
        print("View did load")          
        uid = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
        locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/users/").child("\(uid)").child("locations")
        initialSetUp()
    }
```

The output I am receiving looks something like this

```
View did load
initially set up
observing event
user does not have username(or user does have username if I use a different account)
observing event
user does not have username(or user does have username if I use a different account)
```

My Firebase data structure:

[image: ScreenShot]

Here is what happens when I print snapshot

```
observing event
Snap (FJpA8PGCmwPRT9xjdrZENMIH8wJ3) {
    email = "test@gmail.com";
    id = 10207417529265514;
    name = "Jason";
}
```

I am happy to provide more information if needed but I figured it might be something within the function.

Comment: Several things can cause that, however, adding a *print(snapshot)* in place of the if-else may be revealing. Post that output and perhaps a snippet of your Firebase structure.

Comment: Can you please add more of your code? Something may be simply calling initialSetUp() multiple times

Comment: @ThunderStruct Of course! Although I don't think that's the case, as it is only logging initially set up once and I did a pretty thorough search through my code.

Comment: If your observe event was being called twice, there should be two snapshots printed. Also, your 'outside' firebase defines a var: snapshot, and then the 'inside' observe that checks for a duplicate username redefines the snapshot and re-uses it. Probably better to make those var names unique. Does any of the code after the //do stuff comment fire? There are several print statements or dialogs that should appear.